# Sinonjs fakeserver - multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, qunit, sinon

I use QUnit together with sinon. How can I make sinon's [fakeserver](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server) respond to chained ajax called made from the same method?

```
module('demo', {
    beforeEach: function(){
        this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    },
    afterEach: function(){
        this.server.restore();
    }
});

test('chained ajax calls', function(assert){

    this.server.respondWith('GET', '/foo', [200, 
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, '{ "foo": 1 }' ]);

    this.server.respondWith('GET', '/bar', [200, 
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, '{ "bar": 1 }' ]);

    var successCount = 0;

    $.get('/foo', function(data){
        successCount++;
        $.get('/bar', function(){
            console.log('bar success');
            successCount++;
        });
    });

    this.server.respond();
    assert.strictEqual(successCount, 2);
});
```

My issue above is that I only get the response from one of the methods. Is the fakeserver able to handle this?

**Update:** It seems like adding another `server.respond()` solves the problem. But there must be a better way, right?

According to the docs, it sounds like one call should to the job, regardless of ajax call count:

> server.respond();
>   Causes all queued asynchronous requests to receive a response.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qj20r5m/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I thought `server.repond()` was supposed to do that as well. In any case, I usually set up my fake server(s) to auto respond instead. Unless you need to inspect requests before responding this seems to be easier:

```
var server;
QUnit.module('fake server tests', {
    beforeEach: function() {
        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

        // *** it's this option I'm referring to...
        server.autoRespond = true;

        server.respondWith('GET', '/foo', [200, { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            '{ "foo": 1 }'  
        }]);

        server.respondWith('GET', '/bar', [200, { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            '{ "bar": 1 }'  
        }]);
    },
    afterEach: function() {
        server.restore();
    }
});

QUnit.test('do some ajax', function(assert) {
    var done = assert.async();

    doTwoAjaxCalls(function () {

        // whatever your assertions are...
        // (of course, your method would need to perform the callback...)

        done();
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at your updated code we can see why you need to call `respond()` twice: the first call to respond "releases" the initial ajax request (to `/foo`) from its queue, which then calls the first success callback. Within  that callback you initiate the second ajax call, which Sinon then holds until you call `respond()` yet again.

In other words, calling `respond()` will make Sinon release all currently held ajax requests, but in your case, only one is held at a time. Using the `autoRespond` option I mention above eliminates this need as Sinon "responds" immediately, but I do believe you need to make the test asynchronous in this case (or at least, it is best practice).

Good luck!

Comment: Oh, I thought the fake calls were executed synchronously, thus I didn't use `assert.async`. Is there any way to execute the calls in a synchronous manner?

Comment: Just to elaborate: In all the samples with a single ajax calls, it seems like you can wait for the response without stopping QUinit (e.g. http://www.kenpowers.net/blog/advanced-features-in-sinon/ "`Make assertions, onces again, everything is synchronous.`"). However, with nested calls like above, it seems like you have to make QUnit wait.

Comment: I've updated my example to make it closer to my real code. The calls are actually nested. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Your second comment is mostly correct if you _don't_ use the `autoRespond` option. In that case Sinon is holding your request in the fake server and waiting for you to call `respond()`, which then executes synchronously. However, if you use `autoRespond` I think it's going to be asynchronous.

Comment: Oh, and to your last comment: yes, the nesting of the calls is the issue with having to call `respond()` twice. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I solved this by checking the server queue and trigger a response while the queue is not empty. That will result in a response for each level of nesting (2 in this case as you say above). Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 3):

The Sinon docs state that `autoRespond` is not suitable for tests as it will execute asynchronously. This defaults to 10ms later, which is just enough to bump to the next frame of execution, potentially causing some race conditions with the tests. I discovered this because I had similar nested AJAX calls that I wanted to test.

I ended up implementing a `respondImmediately` property on the `fakeServer` that will synchronously respond to any request. This just got merged into the project a few weeks ago (v1.14.0), but if you update to the newest version you should be able to get it. [Check out the docs here.](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer).

In your `beforeEach` block instead of setting the `autoRespond` property to true, set the `respondImmediately` property to true. Then remove all the `server.respond()` calls and you should be set!

Comment: Hmm I just tested and it doesn't seem to work. What did I miss? http://jsfiddle.net/3qj20r5m/3/

Comment: Ahh, looks like that's a jQuery-ism that adds a 0ms `setTimeout` on the callback. Here's the nested case using raw xhr: http://jsfiddle.net/3qj20r5m/5/.  Using jQuery you might not be able to get around making your tests asynchronous :/

Comment: I see. What I currently do for my nested jquery ajax calls is to make the server respond as long as there are any queued calls waiting. So I guess I'll keep doing that then. Anyway, thanks a lot for the added comment, hopefully it'll help someone with a similar problem...

Comment: @filur I know it's been a while, but I found a solution to this issue. You can use the `respondImmediately` property, then also use `$.ajaxSetup` to default all ajax requests to be sync. You'll not want to use those settings in prod, of course, but it might clean up your tests quite a bit. Here's your original fiddle, forked and with the `ajaxSetup` block http://jsfiddle.net/r9c44q5a/

Comment: Thanks. I think you missed the `$.ajaxSetup` in your example though? But that's what I'm doing today

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, must not have saved the fiddle. Fixed link is here: http://jsfiddle.net/r9c44q5a/1/